# How to impliment IAudioEffectDefinition for windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8.1, media

I want create custom AudioEffect for MediaComposition in my Windows Phone 8.1 project. How to do it?
I know what i need impliment IAudioEffectDefinition interface for it. I need example. I do not know how to find it.

```
public class CustomAudioEffect : IAudioEffectDefinition
{
    public string ActivatableClassId
    {
        get
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public IPropertySet Properties
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and how i want use it:

```
var audioClip = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(uriTrack);
audioClip.AudioEffectDefinitions.Add(CustomAudioEffect);
```

Any thoughts?